# Does cat never read from terminal?

Tags: io-redirection, cat, stdin

Chapter 43. Redirecting Input and Output of [Unix Power Tools, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596003307) has to say this about cat command:

> Standard input (stdin) normally comes from your keyboard. Many
>   programs ignore stdin; you name files directly on their command line —
>   for instance, the command cat file1 file2 **never** reads its standard
>   input; it reads the files directly. But without filenames on the
>   command line, Unix commands that need input will usually read stdin.
>   Standard input normally comes from your keyboard, but the shell can
>   redirect stdin from a file.

(**emphasis** mine)

Ok but happens when we just type `cat > filename` in the command line? Isn't cat reading from the stdin and stores that that into file "filename"? Is the above excerpt from the book just saying that only the particular form of using cat with a FILE argument never reads from the stdin?

Comment: it says "the command cat file1 file2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't cat reading from the stdin and stores that that into file "filename"?

Yes, when `cat` does not have any filename arguments (or if one of the files is the minus character `-`), it reads from `stdin`.

Perhaps use of the word "never" by the book is a bit misleading, because:

> Is the above excerpt from the book just saying that only the particular form of using cat with a FILE argument never reads from the stdin?

Yes, in that particular instance, `cat` will not touch `stdin`.

Comment: What is the speciality of the `-` character that leads cat to read from `stdin`?

Comment: It's just a common feature of programs to use `-` to mean `stdin`, but the program does actually have to support it. If a program just tries to open a file named `-`, it'll open that file instead of `stdin`

Comment: And under some systems such as Linux, if the program doesn't support `-`, one can use `/dev/stdin` instead.

Comment: The `-` filename argument allows you to say `cat file1 - file2 > great_scott` to get `cat` to read first from `file1`, then from the terminal, and then from `file2`.

Comment: This is actually not correct: *Isn't cat reading from the stdin and stores that that into file "filename"?* `cat` does read from `stdin` but it does *not* concatenate that to *"filename"*, exactly, at least not in the sense most processes do. `cat` always writes to `stdout` - a file descriptor inherited from its parent process. But its parent does all of the opening and assigning and whatever - as is indicated by the shell's `>` redirection operator. `cat` just shoots - the parent process has to do all *filename* aiming.

Comment: It is not misleading to say never in that sentence. One just has to realize that the sentence explicitly speaks about the command `cat file1 file2`. It doesn't say anything about what `cat` does when invoked with different arguments.